# DataReader Returns DBNULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using DataReader to read the rows from my sqlcommand.

my problem is that i want return all columns from my database
and error is that he found DBNull in one column.

how can i do to solved this?

Note: the column which return Null is of type string.

```
while(sqlDataReader.Read())
{
    if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
    {
        mylist.Add(new User()
        {
            Id = (int)sqlDataReader["Id"],
            Name = (string)sqlDataReader["Name"],
            File= (string)sqlDataReader["File"]  <-- This is the one which contains some columns Null
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *IsDBNull()* method from DataReader.

```
if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
{
  while(sqlDataReader.Read())
  {
    if(!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(1)) //pass the column index.
    {
        object value=sqlDataReader[1];
    }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
 File=(sqlDataReader["File"] as string).GetValueOrDefault("");
```

Refer to the documentation for [GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: i can´t select the extension GetValueorDefault but the answer of "CreativeManix" have solved it. But thanks anyway for the help.. Thank you very much.. +1